# Css wordpress slider is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Greetings!

I am using wordpress Blog site http://www.seoindiarank.com . I am facing a problem with it into slider. The slider was showing full size but now it's not showing full height, Even I try other sliders too but all slider are showing same width and height.
I want to show slider as 2000px by 550px. But it's need to be mobile friendly too.

I hope friends will help me in my great problem.

Regards,
Sam

Comment: You need to post the code you are specifically having problems with. A little code could go a long way here!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using viewport or % width to make it mobile friendly. In terms of displaying the correct height, viewport and % heights do a much better job with finished aesthetics.